# "Not Enough Space" when trying to use bootcamp assistant - BUT I DO HAVE ENOUGH SPACE

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, partition, disk-space

I'm trying to partition my hard drive using boot camp assistant. I'm using a 32gb flashdrive, and I have a bit more than 180gb free on mac hard drive. I'm using Sierra 10.12.6.

I'm not very computer savvy, and if anyone can direct me to a VERY user-friendly guide on how to get around this error and partition my drive so I can run windows, I'd be VERY appreciative.

Comment: There are lots of results that come from a search of “boot camp not enough space”.  What did you find/try?  As for a guide, did you start with the [official one from Apple](https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-control-panel/get-started-with-boot-camp-control-panel-bcmp1c70f878/mac)?